# How to open a Chrome window with Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I can't manage to make Watir run properly.

I followed all the instructions step by step, installing Watir and the Chrome drivers, and checked that the drivers and Chrome are the same version, v98.0.

Still, with this simple code:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new
```

I can see the Chrome window open, but after less than a second it closes itself automatically.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Is there any exception that appears?

Comment: No, the window barely popup, close, and the terminal right after end the script and goes to a new command line.

Comment: I tried also with firefox now, I installed geckodrivers and it tells me "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."

Comment: By default, the Chrome window will automatically close at the end of the script. There used to be a flag that you could set if you wanted to keep the window open, but I'm not sure if it's still available.

Comment: it's still available, In Watir 7 — `Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {detach: true}`

Comment: (but you won't be able to send any more Selenium commands to it, so it might not be what you're actually looking for)

Comment: i have same problem before, i add sleep syntax, like sleep 20, or byebug after it

Answer (score 0):

Chrome window automatically closes. That was expected. Write the code as shown below

```
require 'watir'

b=Watir::Browser.new

b.goto 'www.google.com'

b.text_field(name: 'q').set 'Hi how are you'

sleep 20
```

Now you can see after the execution browser remains alive for 20 seconds.

Firefox runs fine for me. Don't load any profile, write as given below

```
require 'watir'

b=Watir::Browser.new :firefox

b.goto 'www.google.com'

b.text_field(name: 'q').set 'Hi how are you'
```